# Change app icon in Visual Studio 2005?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2005, icons, visual-c++-2005

I'd like to use a different icon for the demo version of my game, and I'm building the demo with a different build config than I do for the full verison, using a preprocessor define to lockout some content, use different graphics, etc.  Is there a way that I can make Visual Studio use a different icon for the app Icon in the demo config but continue to use the regular icon for the full version's config?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa381033(VS.85).aspx) you may use preprocessor directives in your *.rc file. You should write something like this

```
#ifdef _DEMO_VERSION_
IDR_MAINFRAME ICON "demo.ico"
#else
IDR_MAINFRAME ICON "full.ico"
#endif
```

Comment: You can indeed use preprocessor directives in your rc file. I'd say this is the way to do it. +1

Comment: This is the best solution.  I didn't realize that it was working at first because explorer cached my icon, so I also discovered that you can set the conditions via that icon properties in the resource viewer.

Answer (score 2):

What I would do is setup a pre-build event (Project properties -> Configuration Properties -> Build Events -> Pre-Build Event).  The pre-build event is a command line.  I would use this to copy the appropriate icon file to the build icon.

For example, let's say your build icon is 'app.ico'.  I would make my fullicon 'app_full.ico' and my demo icon 'app_demo.ico'.  Then I would set my pre-build events as follows:

Full mode pre-build event:

```
del app.ico | copy app_full.ico app.ico
```

Demo mode pre-build event:

```
del app.ico | copy app_demo.ico app.ico
```

I hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

This will get you halfway there: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dotnet/embedmultipleiconsdotnet.aspx

Then you need to find the Win32 call which will set the displayed icon from the list of embedded icons.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know a way in visual studio, because the application settings are bound to the hole project. But a simple way is to use a PreBuild event and copy the app.demo.ico to app.ico or the app.release.ico to app.ico demanding on the value of the key $(ConfigurationName) and refer to the app.ico in your project directory.