# How to change the default *.exe icon in C/C++?

Tags: c++, c, windows, portable-executable

I want to change the default `.exe` icon to some other icon in C/C++. Does anybody know how to do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Already answered.

[Change app icon in Visual Studio 2005?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72789/change-app-icon-in-visual-studio-2005)

You have to place your .ico file in the resources folder first of course.

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer the question. He wants to know how to set the _**default**_ `.exe` icon.

Answer (score 2):

Use this one: http://www.angusj.com/resourcehacker/

Since you specified that you are using VS2008 I can point you here: [How do I set the icon for my application in visual studio 2008?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320677/how-do-i-set-the-icon-for-my-application-in-visual-studio-2008) (duplicate question)

Comment: Not really a programming solution or a C/C++ solution, but simple and to the point

Comment: Jack i apperciate that u have replied...like steve said..its not a programming solution for it..

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer the question. He wants to know how to set the _**default**_ `.exe` icon.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, if the executable contains many icons, the 1st of them will be the default.
If you have icons resource in your programming environment, place the icon you want first in the list.

**Edit:** since you created an empty project, to add an icon, follow these instructions:

(as I said in my comment, I don't have VS2008, but the steps should be the same)

**Menu: Insert -> Resource -> Import**
  Select "Icon", press the import button and select your icon file.

Now, close the icon editor, and save the resource script in the project folder.
Select "Files View" and add the resource script file in the "Resource Files".
That's it.

Comment: am using vs2008..I do have a folder called"Resources" but there's nothing in it...

Comment: @Rakesh, in VS you can insert resources in your project. I don't have VS2008, but it's very easy to add an icon. Did you create an empty project?

Comment: Yes,I have created an empty project win 32 console app...
If u jus give me an idea of how to do that...it wud be helpful for me

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer the question. He wants to know how to set the _**default**_ `.exe` icon.

Answer (score 1):

if you are using any ide like dev c++, then you can specify the icon you want to appear on your file in project options

Comment: Sorry, but that does not answer the question. He wants to know how to set the _**default**_ `.exe` icon.